# Looking for the perf monitoring tools, on Ubuntu 20.04.3, but on kernel 5.13.0-1017-oem

Tags: apt, kernel, performance

So I'm looking for a way to use the `perf` monitoring tool but I'm on a non-standard configuration. Currently I'm using an OEM 5.13 kernel from Ubuntu on Fossa 20.04.3.

Normally one would install `linux-tools-common` & `linux-tools-generi`c with a probable inclusion of the `linux-hwe-[kernel version]-tools-common` package. Unfortunately all I see are packages for kernels 5.4, 5.8, and 5.11.

My previous kernel was 5.10 which has the same problem, since associated packages for kernel-specific tooling doesn't appear available in the Fossa repos.  Am I out of luck?

Comment: try: sudo apt-get install linux-tools-5.13.0-1019-oem